# SCCM ignoring Application Deployment during OSD

Tags: sccm, sccm-2012-r2

I am trying to do the following deployment with SCCM 2012 R2:

- Lenovo IdeaPad 500S
- Windows 8.1 Professional
- no Domain, Workgroup machine
- one local user with admin rights
- ConfigManager Client
- 8 applications installed during OSD

The TS is working, showing up in Softwarecenter as installed successfully. Except that two of the applications don't get installed during OSD - Google Chrome and Adobe InDesign.

Both applications are successfully installed after OSD through the Softwarecenter, without errors. With other Task Sequences, both applications can - without errors - be installed during OSD and with Softwarecenter.

During Task Sequence Step "Installing Application", it shows that there are 8 applications to install. But those two seem just to be skipped - there are no errors in smsts.log or appenforce.log. In the last one i can only find the apps that get installed, there is no information about Chrome or InDesign.

What i checked:

- Both apps are Deployed for the collection the Laptop is in (Required).
- The Box "Allow this application to be installed from the Install Application Task Sequence action without beeing deployed".
- i compared all the settings of the apps that work with the apps that do not work - i can not find any difference.
- Tested it multiple times - always the same. Chrome and InDesing don't get installed, but after OSD is finished, Configuration Manager is installing both applications with success.

Any ideas where i can look or where the problem could be?

**EDIT:**

Tested again on a VM: i installed both apps during OSD in a TS for installing Domain Clients. Both apps were there directly after OSD. Then i installed the Workgroup TS on the same machine. Chrome and InDesign are missing. AppEnforce.log does not show a sign of them... just like they did not exist...

**EDIT2:**

Now i know why there is nothing in the logs: i enabled the checkbox "If an application installation fails, continue installling other applications in the list". I was expecting that erros during application deployment would still be loged - this is not the case.

Now i disabled this checkbox, and i see errors for Chrome and InDesign: Error 0x80004005, in combination with Execution Status 24 (Application download failed). I still don't see the problem, since the same applications can be installed with other Task Sequences or after OSD with the CMClient. Both times no errors...

**EDIT3**:
I can't explain why, but after i did what Omnomnomnom recommendet, Chrome is installing during OSD. InDesing is not. I now even completely deleted the application in SCCM and recreated it. Did not change anything... I think i have to go to Microsoft Support...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of our Microsoft Support Center, if finaly found a way to install all the applications during OSD: I had to put Adobe InDesign and Adobe Illustrator in their own TS Step, with reboots in between. After that, all apps are deployed during osd.

This seems more like a workaround than a solution - but it works, so i will stick with that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use some Kind of End-Point-Protection or Data Loss Prevention System? I encountered this problem, when system blocked the copying of certain file types.

Comment: Only the System Center Endpoint Protection Client is installed with the Task Sequence.
What boogles my mind is that all other applications are installed - so there is no basic problem with SCCM App Deployment. And the Apps are installed during other Task Sequences and with CMClient - so no basic problem with the files themselves...

Answer (score 0):

Does the installation work on OSD's where the pc is joined to the domain? If so, what I was thinking was, since you're getting 0x80004005 access denied. you may have to allow anonymous connections to your distribution point. I guess Workgroup clients would not know how to authenticate to the DP.

[image]

Comment: I just found this option and enabled it, but i always thought workgroup machines access the DP with the network access accounts... Well i enabled it and it will report soon.
IF this works, i would still not understand why all the other apps installed without problem...

Comment: Chrome is installed!
InDesign is not...  I'm getting crazy...